# Is ConcurrentHashMap::computeIfAbsent atomic per key or per ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: concurrency, locking, concurrenthashmap

In a call to ConcurrentHashMap::computeIfAbsent I use a slightly expensive mappingFunction. The mappingFunctions are safe to execute concurrently if and only if they are for different keys.
I'm wondering if the mappingFunctions are executed concurrently for different keys. If this is not the case, each mappingFunction would be executed one-at-a-time, leading to unnecessary waiting time. To fix this I would need to write more complex code and use putIfAbsent.
Does anyone know if mappingFunctions are executed concurrently if they are for different keys?

The documentation states:

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically, so the function is applied at most once per key.

This may or may not answer my question, depending on how you read it

Comment: Locking is done on the hashbin, so roughly per-key but is internally spec'd as _"Lock contention probability for two threads accessing distinct elements is roughly 1 / (8 * # of elements) under random hashes."_

Comment: @BenManes thanks for the reply, sounds like I shouldn't use computeIfAbsent for this scenario as performance would become unpredictable

Comment: it’s usually not a problem because collisions are rare in larger maps. You can use initialCapacity if the map  won’t grow much. Since reads are the common case the performance is often excellent